# Firebase create push twice android

Tags: android, firebase, push

Sorry for my english. Before works everything fine. But after i dont know what i have 2 push in same time, it look like i have 2 thread, and each thread create own notification. I check, server send me 1 notification, but android device create 2 notification. Why? I spend many time but i cant fix this problem. Plese if you know give me advice

app gradle

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name="push.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.nga" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="push.FBMnotification"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("GcmBroadcastReceiver", "GcmBroadcastReceiver");

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                FBMnotification.class.getName());

        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

FBMnotification

```
public class FBMnotification extends IntentService {

 public FBMnotification() {
        super("firebase");
    }

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    //create push
    }
    }
```

I cant extends on FirebaseMessagingService because i cant create my custom notification when application is closed. FirebaseMessagingService create own notification without need for me fields and intents

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Receiver` and a `Service` with action `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />`. I'm no sure, but I think that is the reason. Take a look at the example from my own project which works properly.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".service.NotificationsListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I just have this `Service` to receive all notification.

```
public class NotificationsListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {

        sendNotification("You have a new order to release");

    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {

        String _jsonUser = SharedPreferencesUtils.getString(this, SharedPreferencesUtils.Constants.LOGGED_USER_KEY);

        Intent _intent;

        if (_jsonUser != null) {

            UserVO _user = new Gson().fromJson(_jsonUser, UserVO.class);

            Session.putObject(Session.Key.USER, _user);

            _intent = new Intent(this, OrderListActivity.class);

        }
        else {

            _intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);

        }

        _intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent _pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, _intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri _sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder _notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(_sound)
                .setContentIntent(_pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager _notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        _notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, _notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but if i `extends FirebaseMessagingService` this is meen when app is closed, android will be create own notification whithout my custom intents and fields. In field `data` in json i have `chatType = null actId = null planId = null moveType = null` and depending on `chatType` i need open different activity and get `planId` and load all history on chat

Comment: I'm not sure what you talked about. However, I'll explain some things based to my own experience. My `NotificationsListenerService` is called all the time no matter if the app is closed or open. Then, into that service I need to check out the app's state (closed or open) to do what I want it to. Got it?

Comment: i add your code in my project. And when app is open works class `NotificationsListenerService` and created custom notifcation. But when app is closed `NotificationsListenerService` not work, android create own notification. I think it because server send me field `"notification": { "title": "just a test", "msg": "Just to verify" }` and when app is closed android these fields create notification. Server cant not send this field, because it need for ios

Comment: Did you add `NotificationsListenerService` into your code and removed your two classes with action `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />`? Because in my project the `NotificationsListenerService` is called whether the app is closed or open.